# How can I have a UITabBar instead of a UIToolBar on a UINavigationController?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbar

I have `UINavigationController` with `UITableViewController` as the root view controller. `UINavigationController` has a an optional `UIToolBar`, but I want to have a `UITabBar` instead. I don't need a `UITabBarController`because I don't want selecting tab bar items to change the view, just the contents of the same view. My app is a basic RSS reader which displays the items in the table view and I want to use the `UITabBar` to select from 2 or 3 different RSS feeds, refreshing the existing table view in the process, not switching to a different table view.

If I add a `UITabBar` manually to the `UITableViewController` (as it seems impossible to do this form IB) it is anchored to the last cell in the table view, so not only is it not usually visible, but it also moves around. I can't seem to find any way to do what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution will probably be to use a UIViewController instead of a UITableViewController. This way you can have both a UITabBar and a UITableView, both **subviews** of your view controller's view.

The [UITableViewController class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) describes exactly what behavior UITableViewController provides over a plain UIViewController (such as being the delegate and data source, deselecting rows, etc.) — you should implement all this this so everything works as it should.

Comment: and switching from a tableviewcontroller to a UIViewController with a table is really not a painful process at all.

Comment: Nope, you just have to implement a few things to act like a UITableViewController.

Comment: I tried switching my UITableViewController to a UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> and my app just crashes in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions when it calls [self.window makeKeyAndVisible]. I guess something must be screwed up in the nib.

Comment: It was a SIG_ABRT, but I've fixed it now. The problem was that in switching to a regular UIViewController I forgot to link the view outlet to my view in IB. All working now, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can make the `UITableViewController` a `UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>`, and then hook it up in a nib with your TabBar. You can find the `UITableViewDelegate` protocols [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDelegate). Hope that helps!